# Python tkinter 3.5 Image Path from Entry stored in numbers

Tags: tkinter

I'm writing a tkinter application where the user is able to Enter a certain image path, which than can be uploaded and put onto a canvas. While trying the resize this image I realized that the path gets stored quite differently than entered.

e.g.
C:/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/image.jpg

entered into:

image_path = Entry(path_frame)

is stored as:

.326471236408.326497004008.326497004176.326497004232

When printed with print(image_path)

Does someone know, what these numbers mean or how they could represent an image path?

Thanks!
I'm working on a windows 8.1 system with python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The numbers represent the internal name for the Entry widget. They are absolutely unrelated to your data. Widgets exist in a hierarchy, and the full name represents that hierarchy. So, the parent frame is named ".326471236408.326497004008.326497004176", the parent of that frame is ".326471236408.326497004008" and so on.

If you want the value that is entered into the entry widget you must call the `get` method:

```
print(image_path.get())
```